# Creating views in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm following this tutorial in creating mongo views 
https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/01/13/mongodb-3-4-views/

The issue here is when i run the command

```
db.createView('employee_names','employee', [{ $project : { _id : 0, "fullname" : {$concat : ["$FirstName", " ", "$LastName"]}}}])
```

I get an error saying createView is not a function

[image]

My mongo version is 3.4. What am i missing .

[image]

Comment: can you try to run the same command directly from shell and see if it prompt the same error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views work in MongoDb since version 3.4, so instead of RoboMongo one might need Robo 3T. And of course this will work is shell as well. (Assuming old installations are upgraded to 3.4 as described at https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/3.4/#upgrade.)

Answer (score -1):

//There are two collection state and City I would Like to create view on them 
 db.createView(

... "statedistrict", //View Name

...  "States", //First Collection Name

...  [

...  {$lookup:{from:"Districts",localField:"StateId",foreignField:"StateId", as:"trial"}},

...  {$project:{"_id":0,"StateId":1,"StateName":1,"trial.DistrictName":1}}

...  ]

...  )

//After Pressing Enter You Will get below ok message.
{ "ok" : 1 }

//Then pass the below command to see the result/record

> db.statedist.find().pretty()

0 means - don't display

1 means - display

From 1st collection I need all to display except _id. So, only _id is kept 0

From 2nd collection I don't need many. So, I have used trial.not_required_field_name : 0 (you can use any name instead of trial)